# How can I write a file in smb using R?

Tags: r, smb

I want to write a file in an smb folder but I am not able to do this and have seen nothing of how to do it with R.

What I have tried is:

```
dir.create(path="domain\\user:pwd@smb://Ipadress/folder/newfolder/,recurisive=TRUE)
```

But this gives me this error:

```
cannot create dir 'domain\user:pwdd@smb:\IPaddress', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

Using Windows folder explorer, I can enter to the folder and create directories

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact command you run but there is a typo and a missing quote in your command. Try `dir.create(path="domain\\user:pwd@smb://Ipadress/folder/newfolder/",recursive=TRUE)`

Comment: This not works, but thanks!